# Mvc start page using areas on azure with domain

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, url-routing

I have an mvc web app that uses areas. On my developer machine the website starts up with the correct page. In my vs studio in the settings I have set the start action to my area. I am having trouble getting this to work on azure.

The starting area is authentication.

On azure I have a custom domain, lets call it "mydomain.co.za".
When I call up the domain, it says "The resource cannot be found."

I have to call "mydomain.co.za/authentication".

I need it to route to the authentication by just using mydomain.co.za
Is there specific config needed in the web config? Please assist.

I think it can be achieved with the rewrite rule, however, I am struggling to fit this in.

Currently I have a rule to convert from http to https, but not sure where to fit the area in

```
<directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
        <httpRedirect enabled="false" destination="https://mydomain.co.za" exactDestination="true" />
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="http to https" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.mydomain.co.za/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

I am quite new to azure so I am also not sure if this needs to be done in the web config, or if I can configure it in the azure web app settings?

Comment: The program is modified according to my answer, no need to modify anything in portal or web.config.

Comment: Does my answer useful to you ？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your description, I concluded that what you want is the page `A.cshtml` in Areas as the starting page. The Startup Page in the Areas area requires authentication. If no verification is passed, go to `authentication.cshtml` for login verification.

If there is no error in my summary, the point you need to pay attention to is not `rewrite`. It should be the actual `routing configuration`. I will show the screenshot below for the specific operation steps. All have been deployed to azure for testing, and the test passed without problems.

You can [download my demo for test](https://github.com/Jason446620/areaproj).

*`RouteConfig.cs`*

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        var route = routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { "areaproj.Areas.Admin.Controllers" }
        );
        route.DataTokens["area"] = "Admin";
    }
```

*`Areas/Admin/Views/Home/Index.cshtml`* (startup page)

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        bool IsAuth = false;
        if (IsAuth)
            return View();
        else
            return View("~/Areas/Admin/Views/Home/test.cshtml");
    }
```

[image]

Comment: This works and has solved my problem. Thank you very much good sir